# Edits no longer triggering On_Edit triggers

Tags: google-apps-script

After months of seamless use, a sheet I made became unable to trigger a simple on_edit trigger. Ive tried renaming the function and getting a regular trigger for it, but still no luck.

Comment: Installed on_edit trigger or onEdit simple trigger?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.